# DIfference between objects in console on chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, google-chrome-devtools

When I print one of my objects (created via ajax calls) to the console I am getting back:

```
Object
discreet: Array[2]
range: Array[2]
__proto__: Object
```

But when I manually create the object I am correctly getting back:

```
Object {range: Array[2], discreet: Array[2]}
discreet: Array[2]
range: Array[2]
__proto__: Object
```

Could someone explain to me the difference between these two objects, and why I am unable to access the properties of the first object?

Edit: The first object is being created by:

```
var obj = {}

$http.get('/discreet').then( function(data) { obj.discreet = data } );
$http.get('/range').then( function(data) { obj.range = data } );

print(obj);
```

The second I am hand crafting:

```
var obj = { range: [1,2], discreet: [1,2] }
print(obj);
```

Comment: We'll need to see your print call too, if possible.

Comment: Did you tried it in another browser?

Comment: First, I don't really see the different between your outputs; the second result doesn't look like any Chrome console output I've ever seen (i.e. an object litteral immediately after the "`Object`"). Second, the problem is certainly caused by the fact that your `$http.get` functions are asynchronous and their callbacks do not fire until after you prit out the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of misunderstanding asynchronous programming. Here's what you need to know:

1. JavaScript is single-threaded, so it can only do one thing at a time.
2. The callback function in `.then` attached to `$http.get` is asynchronous -- it is *not* immediately executed. Instead, it is *queued up for execution* whenever the Ajax request returns from the server.
3. Asynchronous callbacks cannot run until the current function has completed. They cannot commandeer the execution thread, but must patiently wait for the current function to finish using it.

Thus, when `print(obj);` is run, `obj` has not yet been assigned any properties because neither asynchronous callback has had a chance to run.

If you *do* see properties when you expand the `Object` that is produced on the console, it's because Chrome is lazy about supplying properties for objects printed in the console. It will only ask the object for its properties when you actually click to expand it (at which time the callbacks will have completed).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is simply being `print`ed before the `xhr` response has returned, so the object is empty at the time it is logged.

The second one is logged after it has been populated.

Comment: why am I able to expand it to see the values that have been assigned from the ajax call then?

Comment: The actual underlying object in the console is a reference, but the printed "Object" text is just a string representation at the time you printed it. The first print() call doesn't have any values, so no data shows up after the "Object" printed text. When you expand it later, it *does* have values (the reference is updated) so you can expand it.